How to interpret XML’s case sensitivity and case preference in the context of the encoding declaration?
I’m trying to get my head around the thinking behind XML’s case sensitivity in the context of the encoding
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Seen in the context of
Is the XML declaration tag case sensitive?    and
Is XML case-sensitive?
Plus the XML specification
https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#:~:text=XML%20processors%20should%20match%20character%20encoding%20names%20in%20a%20case%2Dinsensitive%20way
Other than the encoding’s value, the declaration <?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?> clearly is case sensitive as by the standard.
Now two things that I’m not sure about.
If I understood correctly:

The encoding’s value, e.g. UTF-8 remains case sensitive.I.e. both UTF-8 and utf-8 remain “different”, but their evaluation should be case insensitive, thereby making them equivalent.
With respect to UTF-8 and UTF-16, the specification’s preference seems to be the uppercase.Quote: In an encoding declaration, the values " UTF-8 ", " UTF-16 " […] SHOULD be used
I.e. the lowercase utf-8 and utf-16 appears to be discouraged.

I’m particularly concerned about the lowercase utf-8, which used to be my preference, but it seems that I really should have used the uppercase UTF-8. Or does this even matter in 2024?

The w3 recommendation clearly states that encoding names SHOULD be parsed case insensitive.

XML processors SHOULD match character encoding names in a case-insensitive way

Above that paragraph it's the regular expression that defines encoding names and it contains upper and lower case characters so utf-8, Utf-8, UTF-8 are all accepted.

[81]      EncName    ::=      [A-Za-z] ([A-Za-z0-9._] | '-')* /* Encoding name contains only Latin characters */


Agreed that utf-8 Utf-8 UTF-8 are all accepted, but does this mean that using the uppercase UTF-8 in UTF-8 […] SHOULD be used was unintentional or simply as an example? It says UTF-8, not utf-8.

I think it refers to the encodings themselves and not to the way they are written. To me, the regular expression is conclusive: case-insensitive.
